# Why we use areal density to measure thickness in different practicals of physics?

Tags: experimental-physics, solid-state-physics, nuclear-physics

In many experiments like finding the gamma and beta absorption coefficients we use the thickness of aluminium foils in $gm/cm^{-2}$. Why we do that?, Shouldn't it be possible to only denote thickness in mm?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's not $\rm g/cm^{-2}$. It's $\rm g/cm^{2}$ or $\rm g\cdot cm^{-2}$.

The answer to your question is "Yes: you can specify thickness in millimeters". Call that thickness $d_{\rm rad}$, the radiation length in "length" units.

The thickness in $\rm g/cm^{2}$ is:

$$ L_{\rm rad} = \rho d_{\rm rad} $$

where $\rho$ is the density of the material

For electromagnetic interactions the approximate formula is used:

$$ L_{\rm rad} = 1433{\rm g\, cm^{-2}}\frac A{Z(Z+1)(11.319-\ln{Z})}
$$

Note that it depends only on $Z$ and $A$, the actual density of the material irrelevant. Areal density is the most fundamental form of the radiation length. When the experimentalists are designing experiments and instruments, they must then divide by the density to get a physical length.

Comment: The question is why we prefer the gm/cm^2 not if we can do that or not. I know we can do that but is there some reason for that?

Comment: I explained it. You want a number that doesn’t depend on macroscopic material properties, just on the properties of the atom